# Presenting View Controller in SwiftUI

Tags: view, swiftui, presentviewcontroller

How to achieve what the following Objective-C code achieves with SwiftUI? I haven't been able to get a firm grasp on the ideas presented.

```
    [self presentViewController:messageViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You want to look for `UIViewRepresentable`, there are plenty of tutorials showing how to use UIKit views and view controllers inside SwiftUI.

Comment: I am little bit confused of what the point of the question is. Do you want to know how to present any View with FullScreen?

Comment: @Kyokook You're right. I want to know how to present a modal view in the middle of the screen on top of the super view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As there is no provided related code, so in pseudo-code it would look like the following

```
struct YourParentView: View {
   @State private var presented = false
   var body: some View {

      // some other code that activates `presented` state

      SomeUIElement()
         .sheet(isPresented: $presented) {
             YourMessageViewControllerRepresentable()
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It definitely improved my understanding after tinkering a little bit. However, I have a follow-up question: I've read a little about Representables but they seem to be designed to use UIViews. Is this also the way to use some old Objective C View in sheet? In other words, are Representables used for wrapping other views than UIView to present a view on top of the superview when a particular action is taken?

Comment: @Ali, it is possible to represent either exact UIView, including all subviews of course,  (by UIViewRepresentable), or entire UIViewController (by UIViewControllerRepresentable). If you have set up Objective-C/Swift bridge correctly then your UIView/UIViewController will work as well - there is no differences.

Answer (score 10):

Until ios 13.x, there is no way provided by SwiftUI. As I had the same need, wrote a custom modifier of View to achieve it.

```
extension View {
    func uiKitFullPresent<V: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, style: UIModalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen, content: @escaping (_ dismissHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> V) -> some View {
        self.modifier(FullScreenPresent(isPresented: isPresented, style: style, contentView: content))
    }
}

struct FullScreenPresent<V: View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var isAlreadyPresented: Bool = false
    
    let style: UIModalPresentationStyle
    let contentView: (_ dismissHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> V
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if isPresented {
            content
                .onAppear {
                    if self.isAlreadyPresented == false {
                        let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: self.contentView({
                            self.isPresented = false
                            self.isAlreadyPresented = false
                            UIViewController.topMost?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }))
                        hostingVC.modalPresentationStyle = self.style
                        UIViewController.topMost?.present(hostingVC, animated: true) {
                            self.isAlreadyPresented = true
                        }
                    }
                }
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

And, you can use it as the following.

```
.uiKitFullPresent(isPresented: $isShowingPicker, content: { closeHandler in
    SomeFullScreenView()
        .onClose(closeHandler) // '.onClose' is a custom extension function written. you can invent your own way to call 'closeHandler'.
})
```

`content` parameter of `.uiKitFullPresent` is a closure that has a callback handler as its parameter. you can use this callback to dismiss the presented view.

It's worked well so far. It looks a little bit tricky though.

As you may know, iOS 14 will bring us a method to present any view in the way you want. Check `fullScreenCover()` out.

Regarding presenting UIViewController written by Objective-C, it would be possible as Asperi mentioned in his post.

**UPDATE**
Here is the full source code I am using so far.
https://gist.github.com/fullc0de/3d68b6b871f20630b981c7b4d51c8373

**UPDATE_2**
Now, I'd like to say that it's not a good approach because the idea underlying doesn't actually seem to match well with the mechanism of SwiftUI.